# How to perform operations on randomly selected entry of a matrix in R?

Tags: r

Given a 10 by 10 (or any square) matrix how to randomly select an entry and subtract that value from itself and then add the value of that randomly selected entry to the value of another randomly selected entry of the same matrix?

Comment: provide and example of your data frame and output you are hoping to get. Add screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat a matrix like a vector in this respect.

```r
set.seed(69)
my_mat <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
i <- sample(length(my_mat), 1)
j <- sample(length(my_mat), 1)
my_mat[j] <- my_mat[i] + my_mat[j]
my_mat[i] <- 0
my_mat
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71  177    91
#>  [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
#>  [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
#>  [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
#>  [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
#>  [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86     0
#>  [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
#>  [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
#>  [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
#> [10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

Here, you can see that we have taken element 96 and added it to element 81 (both selected at random). Presumably when you say "take the number away from itself", you mean make the entry `0`.

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

another way, using "mask" matrices, might be this:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)

# one for element to substract 0 everywhere else
a<-ifelse(row(x)==sample.int(nrow(x),1),1,0)*ifelse(col(x)==sample.int(ncol(x),1),1,0)

# one for element to add 0 everywhere else
b<-ifelse(row(x)==sample.int(nrow(x),1),1,0)*ifelse(col(x)==sample.int(ncol(x),1),1,0)

# and the answer: substract from someplace and add to another place
x - a*x + b*sum(a*x)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   79   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

row 1, column 2 and row 8, column 8 are the affected cells